# Django model max_length from another Django model

Tags: python, django

I have two models.
The model Copy should get the max_length from the model AdSpot without inheriting from it.
And after trying multiple times, I failed to make this work:

```
class AdSpot(models.Model):

    title_max_chars = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def title_max_chars_from_adspot(self):
        return self.title_max_chars
```

```
class Copy(models.Model):
    adspot = models.ForeignKey(AdSpot, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    def title_max_chars_from_adspot(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.adspot.title_max_chars_from_adspot
    title = models.CharField('Name', max_length=title_max_chars_from_adspot, default="")
```

The error is

```
polls.Copy.title: (fields.E121) 'max_length' must be a positive integer.
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: try `max_length=int(title_max_chars_from_adspot)`

Comment: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'function'`

Comment: Ok try `max_length=title_max_chars_from_adspot(self)`

Comment: Which behavior do you expect? Each row in `Copy` model must have different column `title` width depending on linked `AdSpot` row?

Comment: You can't use a computed value there because that is a database constraint, and it needs to exists when you apply the migration.  You will need to validated that on your `save` method.

Comment: you should try like this:`max_length=Copy.title_max_chars_from_adspot(self)` OR `max_length=int(Copy.title_max_chars_from_adspot(self))`

Comment: not working `NameError: name 'Copy' is not defined`

Comment: read my asnwer. And let me know again, what you want to do exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing things in a wrong way. `max_length` should be integer, and your are passing `python`'s `FunctionType` object. `title_max_chars_from_adspot` is a property of `Copy` class
and you do not have instance of `Copy` class (You will never get it during `makemigration/migration`) process. The only way is to pass `int` `max_length=5` for example, or write `@staticmethod` `@classmethod` for `Copy` class (But this case, it will be impossible to get access on `ForeignKey` object). Change strategy.

```
class AdSpot(models.Model):

    title_max_chars = models.IntegerField(default=22)

class Copy(models.Model):
    adspot = models.ForeignKey(AdSpot, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    default_length = 255
    for field in AdSpot._meta.fields:
        if field.name == 'title_max_chars':
            default_length = field.default
    title = models.CharField('Name', max_length=default_length, default='') # default value of title_max_chars (22 this case) from AdSpot will be set as a max_length of title
```

Comment: thanks, I did some initial test and this is working

Answer (score 0):

You are setting Adspot.title_max_chars to a default equals to 0 
However max_length always should be a positive integer. 
try not to provide a default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PositiveIntegerField` in place of `IntegerField`.

```
class AdSpot(models.Model):

    title_max_chars = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def title_max_chars_from_adspot(self):
        return self.title_max_chars
```

Comment: `Copy.title: (fields.E121) 'max_length' must be a positive integer.`